# Sublime Text 2 : focus on the python console

Tags: console, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext2

Is there any shortcut to switch the focus between the current file and the python console ?
I'd like to jump back and forth without showing/hiding the console (with Ctrl+`) everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ctrl+1` to focus on file. (Focus on 0-th group).

And use to Ctrl+` to switch to console. If you're doing it right — console won't hide.